# Python Tkinter dynamic autoscroll to view a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I am planning to make a "side window" in my `tkinter` application that just shows a list, and automatically scrolls to the bottom of it.

The purpose is that the window will be seen in a huge screen for an audience, and each element in the list is a score for a participant in a competition.

So what i would like to achieve is for example:

The window pops up, shows the first 5 participant and their score, than slowly moves down, so not it shows from the second to the sixth participant, then from third to the seventh etc.

I searched some `set` option for a scrollbar, but i could not find any, but i found a `yview` option for a `listbox`. However, when i try to cycle through a `listbox`, and set its `yview` then sleep lie 1 sec it does not show the correct element, it actually waits for the entire duration, and then jumps to the last element.

The test code i used look like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

def a():
    for i in range(1000):
        listbox.yview(i)
        sleep(1)

master = Tk()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
for i in range(1000):
    listbox.insert(END, str(i))
listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
Button(master,text="start",command=a).pack()

mainloop()
```

Is there a better way to make something like this? Is there a way to correct my code to show the actual position in the list after every sleep cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works, but its not so elegant.

If I `master.update()` after each sleep, it works.